# Is the Game Center "Lock out" feature in iOS 7 restricted to the sandbox or production as well?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

Apparently in iOS 7, if you dismiss the authentication dialog three times in a row, your game will be permanently locked out of game centre, and the only way to get it working again is to "Reset all settings".

My questions are:

1)Does this happen in the production environment once you release to the app store?

2) If it does happen in production, then when is the right time to show the authentication view controller in your game?

According to Apple's documentation, one must authenticate into game centre as soon as your application starts, perhaps even before loading game graphics and animation etc. But if this is the case, then its possible that users who haven't use game centre before will have a tendency to dismiss the dialogue. If they dismiss it thrice, it is unlikely they will ever use game centre with your app, and there isn't even any way for the app to "know".

If you show the authentication dialogue later, then your game won't be able to receive invitations until the player authenticates. I guess this is ok - but not ideal, and I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

EDIT: As I do not have any production apps with iOS 7, I don't fully understand how to handle this. I've been reading the other questions on Stack Overflow, and while they explain how to reset the device, it is unclear how to be prepared for production.